# Open source or low cost "log shipping" program

Tags: sql-server, backup

I have written a log shipping program a number of times.  It is a simple program that is used to maintain a warm fail over box for SQL Server.

It has two pieces.  On the live dB server it:

- Does full and transaction backups and removes old files

On the backup server it:

- Copies the backups from the live box
- Restores the backups or trans into databases that are set to recovery
- zips the backups
- deletes them based on retention

If there is a failure, the program can go through each database on the backup server and set them to active.

I am looking for an open source or low cost program that does this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MS SQL server 2005 and 2008 already support this.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188698.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188698(SQL.90).aspx